# How can I convert this in a descending order?

Tags: java

I am new in programming and I don't know much. I am having trouble on how to convert this in descending order.

The output showing in my code is:

```java
5 = 2
6 = 1
7 = 3
9 = 2
```

but the output i want is:

```java
9 = 2
7 = 3
6 = 1
5 = 2
```

here is my code

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = new int [] {7, 7, 5, 9, 6, 9, 5, 7};
        int [] count = new int[100];
          int temp = 0;

   
  
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                temp = arr[i];
                count[temp]++;
        }
        


        for(int i=1; i < count.length; i++){
            if(count[i] > 0 && count[i] == 1){
                System.out.printf("%d = %d \n",i, count[i]);
             }
            else if(count[i] >= 2){
                System.out.printf("%d = %d \n",i, count[i]);
            }

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for` loop

```java
for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++)
```

to

```java
for (int i = count.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```